# Setting width of Office add-in task pane

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js

Is it possible to set the width of a Outlook add-in when it gets loaded up. Right now when I click on my addin button on the ribbon, the task pane shows up on the right with a width of about 437 pixels. I would like to increase that width to something like 820 pixels.

Answer (score 3):

That's right, there is no way to specify the width. Besides, in OWA the pane is not resizable..

As alternative, you can use a "UI-less" button (see functionFile/ExecuteFunction manifest declarations) and call displayDialogAsync API to display a dialog with custom HTML content, and you can specify the size of this dialog when you create it.

Answer (score 2):

The task pane add-in doesn't support to set the width for the panel. You can submit the feedback [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you want the task pane add-in to support this feature.

Comment: I see these user voice links on every Office.js forum and all of these are dead. No one knows where to submit feedback now. MS should have redirected the previous link to the new location (or should have created a new one if they haven't).

Comment: The new location to submit requests in in  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632485/how-to-show-taskpane-for-a-javascript-excel-addin-on-the-right-side-instead-of-l