# How to wrap the text in OWA task pane for Office365

Tags: html, css

I am displaying decrypted emails content in OWA task pane.
How can I wrap the text to fit task pane width? Currently text is not wrapped and user have to scroll horizontally to read decrypted content. This is not user friendly so I want the text to be wrapped in task pane.
Alternatively I tried to find way to resize task pane width but it is not implemented yet. 
[Setting width of Office add-in task pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275517/setting-width-of-office-add-in-task-pane)

Answer (score 0):

The content of your Task Pane add-in is just HTML+CSS. You can use a variety of CSS styling and layout options to render your text, there's nothing specific to Office for JavaScript or Outlook web add-ins that will help you with this.